# Stripe for one time payment. - Ruby on Rails

Tags: stripe-payments

Can I use Stripe for receiving a one-time payment instead of recurring payments?

If so what settings do I have to make?

Comment: Hey,

I am not 100% sure. But instead of making a Customer (which can be charged multiple times) you just make a charge. Take a look at https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#create_charge and https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#create_customer . Also watch http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, just use the [Stripe::Charge.create](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#create_charge) method. As the payment method, you can either pass in a card directly or reference a Customer whose card should be charged.

Comment: A 3 year old answer and still helpful... Thanks

Comment: Plus look who the answer is from!

Answer (score 3):

You can receive one-time payments via the Stripe dashboard. Go to:

https://dashboard.stripe.com/payments

and click the button for a "+New" payment. That will let you manually enter the cc info. I do this with my [Pairing as a Service](http://www.readysetrails.com/index.php/pairing-as-a-service/) clients all the time... they just read me their card info, and I enter it with the amount I'm charging them and a description. Your account password is then required to complete the charge.

It's fast and easy... I just wish there was a way to let them enter the info directly. Maybe I'll make something like that...

Comment: Huh, since it was described as "not coding related", i presumed OP meant he was looking for a way to actually charge someone a one-off payment. The accepted answer appears to actually be coding related after all... Oh well, I tried!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can just create a Stripe account and use a simple example of Stripe payment for Ruby on Rails I've made recently. Check the code: https://github.com/ab00zar/StripePayment-example

Run the server using your test keys like:

```
PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test_g0XSu8r2ugAETksVJQXJjU30
SECRET_KEY=sk_test_A3rwGLOMNxEKDkaJOTgi4frd rails s
```